# How can I add a unit test to a C++ console program in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

How can I add a unit test to a C++ console program in Visual Studio 2012?

From what I've been able to gather from the MSDN the MS unit test support for C++ can't do this at all, (which doesn't surprise me as the MS C++ unit test support was always shocking).

However in earlier versions of Visual Studio you used to be able to unit test C++ code using Visual Assist, but sadly this doesn't support vs2012.

Does anyone know of a C++ unit test framework with some sort of IDE integration that works with vs2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual studio does support [integrated unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx).  You need to structure your program correctly though.  The way I like to structure my solutions is to have three projects.

- A .lib project that has my source code in it.
- An executable project, linked with the .lib. This calls into the .lib in the main() call
- A test project (exe), linked with the .lib.

Whilst it is possible to use the Visual Studio testing framework, I would recommend [Google test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).  One of the best things about google test is actually [Google mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).  You can get some integration with this [plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f00c0f72-ac71-4c80-bf8b-6fe381548031).

Comment: Thanks, that looks really interesting. I'm guessing the plugin you refer too is actually this though http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f00c0f72-ac71-4c80-bf8b-6fe381548031 I think your link is wrong.

Comment: I've just had a play with this for an hour and I must say I'm very impressed so far. Simple to build, simple to apply (can run test within executable no problem so no extra projects required), with VS2012 Test Explorer integration too. Great.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your tests in [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) and use [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)

Comment: Thanks but if I'm testing C++ code I'd rather stay native than have to mess around with Dotnet too.

Comment: me too, but that's the only way you can have your tests found and run automagically. otherwise you will need to write test suites to insure that all of your tests gets run.